# ROBOT FRAMEWORK: How to make test teardown execute only if test case fails?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I could use the "TEST TEARDOWN" keyword in the header but this gets executed after each test case. Is there any way I can do in the code so that it only executes if the test case fails and if otherwise, skips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword [Run Keyword If Test Failed](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If%20Test%20Failed) was created for that case.
Better have Robotframework documentation always at hand (and browse trough it at least once).

Here is a special note about it:

```
This keyword can only be used in a test teardown. Trying to use it anywhere else results in an error.
```